# Fiddlers Jscript JSON.JsonDecode

Tags: fiddler, jscript, fiddlercore, jscript.net

This is what I have:

`public static var users=Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode('[{key:"20048039", value:"Some Name"}, {key:"204130"...);`

This is what I want:

`users.JSONObject[0].key` or `users.JSONObject[0].value`

This what I use for investigation:

`FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat('output: {0}', users.JSONObject[0]);`

> output: System.Collections.Hashtable

I know c#, but in FiddlerScript I need some help to read these values inside `users`.

What shall I do here ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the solution by myself(ArrayList,Hashtable):

`users.JSONObject[0]["key"])`